# Tasking VX assembler, using symbolic name instead of register name

Tags: assembly, infineon

I am not a beginner programmer, but just started to use the Tasking VX assembler
(manual http://www.tasking.com/support/tricore/tc_user_guide_v6.0.pdf). I cannot believe I am asking such a simple question, but after reading the Tasking VX assembler manual twice I cannot find an answer to the simplest of things:
can I use a symbolic name instead of original register name?

Something like:

```
 loop_i = d3          ; d3 register, wishing to use symbolic name loop_i instead
                      ; (assembler doesn't allow the above definition)      
 mov16    loop_i, #4  ; this is what I want in the code
 mov16    d3, #4      ; this is what I must use instead
```

Thank you for forgiving me for an elementary question.

Comment: Which tasking vx assembler you use? What is target CPU? Can you give link to manual?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this as it just obfuscates your code, making it less clear what registers are actually being used by the code.

Comment: @ross: yes, I agree. Only thing is that the source code I received (from another compiler for this processor) has these '=' defines, many thousands of them.
Well I guess I will write a script to remove them from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.tasking.com/support/c166/c166_user_guide_v2.1.pdf TASKING VX-toolset for C166 User Guide, section "3.3. Operands of an Assembly Instruction", register operand should be of form defined in "3.5. Registers" section:

> The following register names, either upper or lower case, should not be used for user-defined symbol names in an assembly language source file:
>
> ```
>  R0 .. R15 (general purpose registers)
>  RL0 .. RL7 (byte registers)
>  RH0 .. RH7 (byte registers)
> ```

As I understand, user-defined symbols are for constants or labels; there is no user-defined symbol of type "register" in "3.7.4. Symbol Types and Expression Types". But you may try to use preprocessor with "`.DEFINE`":

> ```
>   .DEFINE symbol string
> ```
>
> Description.
>   With the `.DEFINE` directive you define
>   a substitution string that you can use on all following source lines.
>   The assembler searches all succeeding lines for an occurrence of
>   symbol, and replaces it with string. If the symbol occurs in a double
>   quoted string it is also replaced. Strings between single quotes are
>   not expanded. This directive is useful for providing better
>   documentation in the source program. A symbol can consist of letters,
>   digits and underscore characters (_), and the first character cannot
>   be a digit.

Try this:

```
 .define  loop_i  d3
 mov16    loop_i, #4

 mov16    d3, #4      ; this is what I must use instead
```

PS: http://www.tasking.com/support/tricore/tc_user_guide_v6.0.pdf "TASKING VX-toolset for TriCore User Guide" has similar assembler capabilities, so try `.define`. Only allowed set of register names is different from c166:

> 3.5. Registers
>   The following register names, either uppercase or lowercase, should not be used for user-defined symbol
>   names in an assembly language source file:
>
> ```
> D0 .. D15 (data registers)
> E0 .. E14 (data register pairs, only the even numbers)
> A0 .. A15 (address registers)
> ```

Comment: thank you for explanations. .define fails with the message:
astc E238: string value expected
I looks like the proper answer is: it is not possible using this compiler